# Changing logic - jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I have buttons that add and remove products from the Magento cart, but that's not so relevant in that issue. What I want to do is change the logic of what they are doing. Currently, when the buy button is clicked, the product is added to the cart, the button is "changed" to remove it and all other buttons are disabled for the click. When the remove button is clicked, the product that was added is removed and all other buttons can be clicked again.

I want to change the logic to the following: when the buy button is clicked, the product is added to the cart and the buy button is "changed" to remove (so far everything is the same as it was). But, all buttons remain click-enabled and if any other buy button is clicked, the product that was added is removed and the new product is added.

I've researched and thought in many ways, but I can not find a way to do that.

**Button code:**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<button style="display: none;" type="button" id="cartaoMensagemRemover<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="Remover" class="button btn-cart" onclick="removeCartaotoCart('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Remover</span></span></button>
```

**Ajax requisition code:**

```
function addCartao(product_id){
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
                  data: {
                    product_id: product_id
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {

                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);

                    $j('#cartao').find(':button').not(button).attr('disabled',true);
                    $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();

                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
              });
            }

            function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
                $j.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
                    data:{
                        itemId: itemId
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){

                    },
                    success: function(retorno){
                        var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);
                        $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);
                        $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
                        getSubTotal();
                        getGrandTotal();             
                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "simplified" your code a lot... Since I can't make an example with your PHP.
So the "reproduced" behavior is in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/gxEJXQ).

Now what you need to do, is to keep the added product ID in "memory" in a variable.

On add... If there already is a product ID, call the remove function, then add the other product.

It should be as simple as this.
So here is [another CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BdbeVe?editors=1111) with th modifications to make.

```
var productSelected = "";  // The variable used as a "memory".

function addCartao(product_id){

  if( productSelected != "" ){
    removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);    // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
  }

  console.log("Add "+product_id);
  productSelected = product_id;             // Keep the product id in "memory".

  $('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
  $('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
  $('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).css({'background-color': '#000000','color':'white'});
  //Ajax...

  // In the success callback:
  var button = $('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);
  //$('#cartao').find(':button').not(button).attr('disabled',true);   // Do not disable the other buttons.
}

function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
  console.log("Remove "+itemId);
  productSelected = "";               // Remove the product id from "memory"

  $('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
  $('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
  //Ajax...

  // In the success callback:
  var button = $('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);
  //$('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);   // The other buttons aren't disabled... This line is useless.
}
```